# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot and JPA and SQL Server as database. I want fetch data using native query and store in `List<Object[]>` but whenever I call this query I get exception.

**This is my native query in repository**

```
@Query(value = "select sem.GROUP, sem.MOBILENO, sem.IS_PRAMUKH, sem.VILLAGE, sem.opbal from SAVINGGROUPMST as st right join SAVINGGROUPMEM as sem on st.GROUP = sem.GROUP where st.RP_NO = :id", nativeQuery = true) 
  List<Object[]> getMemberList(@Param("resourceId") BigDecimal resourceId);
```

**This is serviceImp Class**

public List memberList(BigDecimal resourceId) throws Exception {

```
    List<MemberDetails> memberList = new ArrayList<>();
    MemberDetails details = null;
    try {
        List<Object[]> list = memberDetailsRepository.getMemberList(resourceId);
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            for (Object[] objects : list) {
                details = new MemberDetails();

                details.setGroupCode((double) objects[0]);

                BigInteger mobileNO = (BigInteger) (objects[4] != null ? objects[4] : 0);
                details.setMobileno(mobileNO.longValue());

                details.setVillegeName(objects[7].toString() != null ? objects[7].toString() : null);
                details.setOpbal((float) (objects[8] != null ? objects[8] : 0));
                memberList.add(details);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return memberList;
}
```

**After calling method I am getting exception like this.**

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)

[image]

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: i am using  'org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect'

Comment: Try to use org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect. It has registered `java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR (-9)`. BTW, what version of your SQLServer?